# how to assign values to state array in a class component of react

Tags: reactjs

How to assign values to state array in a class component of react?

```
class Dashboard4 extends React.Component {
  state = {
    TotalParts: 0
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    const d = await actions.getTotalParts();

    this.setState({ TotalParts: d[0].Total });
    this.setState({ v_date: d[0].v_date });
  }
}
```

In the above snippet, only one value is getting assigned to `TotalParts` (`d[0].Total`), but I want to assign multiple values to the same from an receiving object called d having two fields Total.

When I declare TotalParts as an array in state. Can any one help me how to assign all Total values in d object to TotalParts?

```
class Dashboard4 extends React.Component {
  state = {
    TotalParts: []
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    const d = await actions.getTotalParts();

    // How to assign multiple values of Total
    // available in d object to TotalParts:[]?
  }
}
```

Expecting all values of Total present in d object to be assigned to TotalParts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the array method [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) on the `d` array and just extract the `Total` values.

```
this.setState({ TotalParts: d.map(element => element.Total) })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by maping through `d` array and then return a new object which contains Total and v_date

```
this.setState({
    TotalParts: d.map(element => {
        return {
            Total: element.Total,
            v_date: element.v_date
        }
    })
})
```